# Python plot data from csv and sort them in plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

[image]I need to plot the data from csv file. yvalues are not in order thats why i need to sort them. I rotate the x axis because the strings are so long. Ho can I do?

```
####My data:####
```

[image]

```
####Code:#####
x = []
y = []

with open('output.csv','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    
    for row in plots:
        x.append(row[1])
        y.append(row[2])
        
plt.plot(x[1:],y[1:], label='Loaded from file!')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Interesting Graph\nCheck it out')
plt.legend()

plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

Comment: you should keep `x` and `y` in one list `data = [ [x1, y1], [x2, y2], ... ]` - so you could read `data = list(plots)` - and then you can use `data.sort(key=lambda i:i[1])` or `sorted(data, key=lambda i:i[1])`. And after that you should split it to separated lists. OR read it in `pandas.DataFrame`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

It seems problem is simpler then I expected and solution is

```
y[1:] = sorted(y[1:])
```

---

**Old answer**

You should keep `x` and `y` as pairs on one list - like this

```
data = [ [x1, y1], [x2, y2], ... ]
```

so you could read it as

```
data = list(plots)
```

and then you can sort it

```
data.sort(key=lambda i:i[2])
```

or

```
data = sorted(data, key=lambda i:i[2])
```

And after that you should split data

```
x = [i[1] for i in data]
y = [i[2] for i in data]
```

---

OR you should read it to `pandas.DataFrame`

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('output.csv')
```

and then you can sort

```
data = data.sort_values(by='TotalTime')
```

and plot it without spliting

```
plt.plot(data['Name'], data['TotalTime']
```

Comment: Name position should not change in plot because when i use what is written above, it is also sorting the name. Name position should should be in same order but total time values' should be in order, I shared a graph photo

Comment: usually people sort all values in all columns. Then you need only `y[1:] = sorted(y[1:])` It is so simple solution that I didn't expected that your problem is so simple.